# Is it bad security to save jwt in cookie to pass it to local storage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, cookies, jwt

In order to get my twitter sign in to work with jwt sessions and angularjs, I have created a jwt with twitter username and display name, passed it as a cookie and saved it to local storage. Here's some relevant code:

Log in users and save cookie:

```
app.get('/login/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
    app.get('/login/twitter/callback', function(req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('twitter' , {session: false} , function(err, user, info) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            var token;
            token = user.generateTwitterJwt();
            // res.status(200);
            // res.json({
            //  "token" : token
            // });
            res.cookie('jwt' , token);
            res.render('login.jade');
        })(req, res);
    });
```

Save to local storage and remove cookie:

```
$scope.twitterTest = function() {
    var jwtCookie = $cookies.get('jwt');
    authenticationService.saveToken(jwtCookie).error(function() {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).then(function() {
        $cookies.remove('jwt');
        var url = '/profile';
        $window.location.href = url;
    });
}
```

I'm wondering if there are any drawbacks to doing this. Any security issues? I'm trying to use jwt and angularjs save to localstorage process because it's how I set up my local login.

Comment: Why don't you directly store the token to the local storage?

Comment: @RaphaelMüllner I couldn't figure out have to get the jwt from the Twitter callback page because post requests are blocked

Comment: I have to admit that I have no idea about AngularJS, but I don't think that your technique has a big security impact. It just doesn't feel clean to me to "buffer" the token in a session before saving it into the local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the browser sessionStorage instead of localStorage, SessionStorage is more secure because it will deleted with browser session end. And directly store it in sessionStorage instead of cookie, cookie is not required in this case.